# Type mismatch error occurring on find method

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find values by comparing 2 sheets and then copy the row to another sheet. Any suggestions?

```
Sub SpecialCopy()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cellval, rng As Range
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim targetSh As Worksheet

    Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("sheet1")
    ws2.Select

    With ActiveSheet  
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With



    For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count

       Set cellval = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:=ws2.Range("U" & i).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If cellval Is Nothing Then

        Else  
            Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(33, i)).Copy Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it the `Find` that is giving the error, or the `Copy`?

Comment: change `Dim cellval, rng As Range` to `Dim cellval As Range, rng As Range` (if you don't _explicitly_ declare a variable type, it's _implicitly_ assumed to be of `Variant` type)

Comment: `Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(33, i)).Copy` seems strange - `i` is being used in your loop to go through column U starting from row 2 and ending on row containing the last cell used in column A, but in the `Copy` you are copying the contents of rows 1 to 33 in column `i`, so B1:B33, then C1:C33, then D1:D33, etc ?!?!

Comment: @YowE3K Find is giving the error -- Type mismatch

Comment: Ahh - I see the problem - you are doing a `Find` in column A of **Sheet1**, starting with the `ActiveCell` - but the `ActiveCell` is on **Sheet2**.  Which cell do you really want the `Find` to start from?

Comment: @YowE3K Trying to Find Value  in column A of Sheet1 where the text to find is in sheet2.. Cell 2

Comment: Yes - but you have said `After:=ActiveCell` and `ActiveCell` at that point is somewhere on Sheet2, so Excel is going to get very confused trying to find something on Sheet1 when you tell it to start searching after somewhere on a  completely different sheet.  So you need to decide where you **do** want the search to start, or else drop the parameter out and just let Excel start wherever it likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel that this is piggy-backing on others' comments above, but nobody has submitted an answer so here is my stab. Makes sense to use your sheet variables as you have defined them rather than ActiveSheet, and make sure you follow this through everywhere.

```
Sub SpecialCopy()

Dim i As Long
Dim cellval As Range, rng As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim targetSh As Worksheet

Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws2
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

For i = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
    Set cellval = ws1.Columns(1).Find(What:=ws2.Range("U" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not cellval Is Nothing Then
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, i), ws2.Cells(33, i)).Copy Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells(targetSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `targetSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A")` should be `targetSh.Cells(targetSh.Rows.Count, "A")` - you should use your sheet variables everywhere ;-)  (And I still don't know what's meant to be happening with the `Copy` - using `i` as a row index, and then also as a column index, seems _weird_.)

Comment: @YowE3K - ha, touche. You are correct of course, though I feel that this is slightly pedantic as the count of rows doesn't vary by sheet (unless there is a chart sheet).

Comment: Once you start qualifying all your other references correctly, there then exists the chance that the ActiveSheet may be in one workbook and the sheets being referred to are in another workbook.  And if the ActiveSheet is in a workbook that has 1048576 potential rows, and the sheets being used are in a workbook that only supports 65536 potential rows, Excel will throw an error trying to access a row that doesn't exist.  (Another one of the lessons I have learned since joining SO!)

Comment: @YowE3K - I guess that could happen. I have changed it above anyway to be on the safe side.

Comment: It doesn't happen very often - but there is usually about one or two questions caused by that issue each month.